# Filter Dropdown datasource

Tags: sxa

I am working on SXA 1.2 along with sitecore 8.2 rev. 161129.

I am trying to build a search functionality using SXA toolbox controls. I tried adding a Filter(dropdown) control to the page, added a class to the facet field to fill this dropdown with certain items in a folder.

I added a class implementing ISimpleFacet which returns an array of strings (Item IDs), and the value of the "Field Name", was a single line text field that has a string value.

Unfortunately the dropdown is not filling any value.. it is still empty. Any idea what I might be missing?

following is the class written to get the items IDs:

```
public class ItemsFacet : ISimpleFacet
{  
    public string[] Filters()
    {
        return new string[2]
        {
            "1bfe1a9765d9451a9c77f9fc7210cb64",
            "c9b58de777584040be1af11253b56a2a"
        };
    }  
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The Facet Filter field that is a Sitecore field, not an SXA one. We didn't modify that functionality in SXA and as far as I remember we never used that field. So there are two options: it's not working in Sitecore or SXA doesn't support custom implementation provided in Facet Filter field. I will try to check this durring incoming week.

Comment: Any news regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a ISimpleFacet class to get values in the drop-down, it is much simpler and can be achieved via CMS only. Assuming that you need to dropdown to filter down the results from broad search query, please do the following:

1. Create your name/value pairs in a folder under the 'Data' section of
       your site, you can use 'Enums' folder and 'Enum' value templates or
       your own one.
2. Add a 'droptree' field in your template that refers to the 'Enums' folder
3. Create a 'Search Scope' for that the page/section, let say you want to search only news articles,  under /sitecore/content/{your-site}/Settings/Scopes
4. Create a 'List Facet' for that field under /sitecore/content/{your-site}/Settings/Facets
5. Switch to experience editor mode for the search page, Drag & drop
       'Dropdown' filter on the page and select the list facet within the
       'Facet' field.

Save and publish and your dropdown values should be coming up.

Comment: can i change the sort order of the dropdown filter, it has only two options: sort by names and sort by count. can i for example sort by date?

Comment: You can, you need to add additional facet for the date field that you want to use, for example 'Published Date' and then refer it in the sort filter.